# How do I use the OpenAI API to prompt a GPT model in python (Google Colab)

Tags: openai-api

How do I use the OpenAI API to prompt a GPT model in python (Google Colab)?

All of the top ranked OpenAI API examples returned by Google search are outdated and do not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install openai

api_key = "INSERT_YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY"
system_requirements = "You are a helpful AI designed to perform tasks."
prompt = "Please summarise this text: The red apple fell off the tree."
model = "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125"    #gpt-3.5-turbo-0125, gpt-4-0125-preview, etc

from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)

def promptGPT(prompt, model, system_requirements):
    try:
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=model,
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": system_requirements},
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
            ]
        )
        return response.choices[0].message.content
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {e}"

response = promptGPT(prompt, model, system_requirements)
print(response)
```